# How to store value of function call to a variable

Tags: haskell

I have this function where I need to check if the `gdc` of the numbers `[1..n]` and `n` is `== 1` and do some calculations then.  So I am stuck because I can't find a way to store the initial value of n to a variable.

For example, if I call the function with the number 7 its a recursion so `n` becomes `6` then `5` etc so I can't `gdc` properly; for example `1-7` then `2 - 7` then `3 -7`. Do you know how I can store the value of `n` to `a` variable ?

```
myproduct :: Integer->Integer

myproduct 0 = 1
myproduct n  
  |gcd n (n from first call)  /= 1 = myproduct (n-1) 
  |otherwise = x
  where 
    x = n * myproduct (n - 1)
```

Comment: Minor nit: the GCD of `n` and `n` is always going to be `n`; you probably need to check for `[1..n-1]` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a helper function (often called `go`) to do the recursion, and use a different variable name in the outermost call than in the recursive call, like this:

```
myproduct :: Integer->Integer

myproduct orig_n = go orig_n
  where
    go 0 = 1
    go n
      |gcd n orig_n  /= 1 = go (n-1)
      |otherwise = x
      where
        x = n * go (n - 1)
```

Comment: It's probably useful to mention that using an 'inner' `go` function is the standard way to do any recursion in Haskell when an extra variable name or parameter is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that works and its pretty cool that you can use another function like that!

Comment: (a side note) this fails to mention explicitly that the "helper function" is defined in the nested scope of the original `myproduct` function. a non-nested (top-level) `myproduct_helper :: Integer->Integer->Integer` would also have access to the original argument value (this is the Prolog way to achieve this, since it doesn't have nested scope). in Haskell/LC-based languages/ turning a nested function into the top-level one by adding parameters to it is known as "lambda lifting".