# How to store tree during recursion? (Huffman decoding)

Tags: haskell, huffman-code

I'm trying to learn Haskell. I am trying to implement a Huffman Tree. The parameters of my decode function are (basically, the 'signature'):

```
decode :: HTree -> [Int] -> [Char]
```

So, given the tree, and a list of numbers, I want to return the decoded message. Suppose `a = 01`, `b = 1`, `c = 001`, `d = 000`.

I know how to do it when I can use two trees for decoding. i.e:

```
decode :: HTree -> HTree -> [Int] -> [Char]
```

Concisely put, keep the first tree as the original tree, and make the other tree go left or right based on the next number in `[Int]` (if it's 0, go left, if it's 1, go right). Repeat this until a leaf is reached, and then add the leaf into the list of `[Char]` and continue using recursion. However, I am trying to do this with just one tree, i.e:

```
decode :: HTree -> [Int] -> [Char]
```

but I can't see how to store the original `HTree` as I traverse through it looking for a leaf. I there a way to do this in haskell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store value of function call to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55133331/how-to-store-value-of-function-call-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a recursive helper function that has access to the original tree:

```
decode :: HTree -> [Int] -> [Char]
decode orig = go orig
  where go :: HTree -> [Int] -> [Char]
        go curr = -- use both orig and curr here
```

Comment: I just realized that as you posted the comment. This should do the trick. Thanks. (will accept the answer soon)

Comment: both this answer and the one in the linked entry fail to mention explicitly that the "helper function" is defined in the nested scope of the original `decode` function. a non-nested (top-level) `decode_helper :: HTree -> HTree -> [Int] -> [Char]` would also have access to the original (this is the Prolog way to achieve this, since it doesn't have nested scope). in Haskell/LC-based languages/ turning a nested function into the top-level one by adding parameters to it is known as "lambda lifting".